# How do I redraw the background, so it will look like my "player" moving in html5-canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is my JavaScript. I have an animate function, I think this is where the redrawing background code goes. I have tried to use document.getElementById to get the id of the canvas, and give the style rule of background: white. But it didn't work. All help is appreciated!:

```
function initCanvas(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
    var cW = ctx.canvas.width, cH = ctx.canvas.height;
    var dist = 10;

    function Player(){
        this.x = 0, this.y = 0, this.w = 50, this.h = 50;
        ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
        this.render = function(){
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        }
    }

    var player = new Player();
    player.x = 100;
    player.y = 225;
    function animate(){
        //This is where I think the background redrawing should go
        player.render();
    }
    var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 30);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        if(key_press == "W"){
            player.y-=dist;
        } else if(key_press == "S"){
            player.y+=dist;
        } else if(key_press == "A"){
            player.x-=dist;
        }  else if(key_press == "D"){
            player.x+=dist;
        }
    });   

}
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
     initCanvas();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple things I've noticed:

1. You didn't declare `var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');`
2. Your `initCanvas()` wasn't firing(It wasn't for me)
3. Your `render()` function should reset the `fillStyle` before it draws your character. Having the `fillStyle` set when initializing the `Player` constructor is useless(It can be overridden).

Here is what your `animate()` function should look like:

```
function animate(){
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    player.render();
}
```

Notice how `fillRect()` clears the canvas before drawing the player.

I have created a working JSFiddle with the fixes [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rrc025gv/1/).

Comment: I did do the document.getElementById I just combined it with the .getContext("2d"). Thanks for the help though!